# Fitting repeated measures in R

Tags: r, measures, nlme

Fitting repeated measures in R, convergence issues. I have the following fit which is one of many datasets and it doesn't converge. I do other sets that do. This dataset and model work in SAS... Could I get some direction in what to do to have this work in R? Things to look at (matrices,option settings,a reference on this topic for r/splus ...).

```
fit.gls <- gls(resp~grpnum+grpnum/day,data=long, corr=cormat,na.action=na.omit)
Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : 
  computed "gls" fit is singular, rank 62
```

I have read the following and still trying to work thru it...
[Converting Repeated Measures mixed model formula from SAS to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819720/converting-repeated-measures-mixed-model-formula-from-sas-to-r)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the data.  `gls` needs to invert a matrix to work (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) for the formula to estimate the covariates).  For you particular data set, that matrix is not invertible.

You can allow for singular values to be allowed with the `control` argument:

`fit.gls <- gls(resp~grpnum+grpnum/day,data=long, corr=cormat,na.action=na.omit,
               control = list(singular.ok = TRUE))`

Be careful with this as you may get bad results!  Always check the model fit afterwards.

Look at the help for `gls` and `glsConrol` for more details about options.